# linq orderby with condition

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

How to order a list with condition

As an example:

I have a list of INTs

`{1,45,63,1,2,100,46,12,2,100}`
in code:

```
int[] ints = {1,45,63,1,2,100,46,12,2,100};
```

I want to order in two ways ASC and DESC means:

```
            switch (this.SortMode)
            {
                case ReportSortMode.DESC:
                    Rank = Rank.OrderByDescending();
                    break;
                case ReportSortMode.ASC:
                    Rank = Rank.OrderBy();
                    break;
            }
```

but i need to get values in condition:

ASC:  {1,1,2,2,12,45,46,63,100,100}

DESC:  {63,46,45,12,2,2,1,1,100,100}

means:
`Where(x =>x < 100)`

possible using `Except` some like :

```
var fakeval = rank.where(x => x<100)
switch (this.SortMode)
{
    case ReportSortMode.DESC:
         Rank = Rank.OrderByDescending().Except(fakeval);
    break;
    case ReportSortMode.ASC:
         Rank = Rank.OrderBy();
    break;
}

//to be full))
public enum ReportSortMode
{
    DESC = 1,
    ASC = 2,
}
```

but it's no work

Comment: Do you want to remove the value `>= 100` or anything else ? put it at the end ? should the rejected value be ordered ?

Comment: no just move to end of the list  : DESC: {63,46,45,12,2,2,1,1,100,100}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **ASC** order you need to change nothing:

```
var intsasc = ints.OrderBy(x=>x);
```

For **DESC** order below code should be OK:

```
var intsdesc = ints.OrderByDescending(x=>x<100 ? 1 : 0).ThenByDescending(x=>x);
```

Result:

```
63 
46 
45 
12 
2 
2 
1 
1 
100 
100
```

Comment: @AleksP, speed of query? It's well known that Linq is powerfull tool but its performance is doubtful. Executing it on HUGE data, it will be slower than custom sorting function.

Answer (score 2):

ASC:

```
ints
    .OrderBy(x => x < 100)
    .ThenBy(x => x)
```

DESC:

```
ints
    .OrderBy(x => x < 100)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x)
```

Note: not entirely sure if true comes before false or the other way around. You might need to change OrderBy to OrderByDescending.

Comment: For descending order it shouldn't be `OrederByDescending().ThenByDesceending()`?

Comment: Not if you look at his examples. In both asc and desc the two 100s are at the end.

Comment: I see: 63 to 1 then 100 ;)

Comment: Exactly, in both cases, so the OrderBy (or OrderByDescending) should be identical for both cases.

Comment: In your ASC code, the `100` are at the beginning (use `OrderByDescending`). Also in ASC case you just have to do `OrderBy(x => x)`.

Comment: Not quite identical. For **ASC** order `ThenBy` is not needed, for **DESC** order, both `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending` are needed.

Comment: It's no work too: there is sequential  `
ASC

100 
100 
1 
1 
2 
2 
12 
45 
46 
63 

DESC

100 
100 
63 
46 
45 
12 
2 
2 
1 
1 

ints

1 
45 
63 
1 
2 
100 
46 
12 
2 
100 
`